# How to filter values in a status history panel with two queries in Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, grafana, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently building a dashboard in Grafana (9.0.6) and try to visualize "AWS Lambda Invocations" and "AWS Visible SQS Messages" with two queries (Metric Search) in a status history panel over the last 24 hours.

Problem is that the SQS Metric has far more datapoints, than the Lambda Metric with datapoints for actual invocations.

**Question:** Is there a way to filter out the values equal to 0 from SQS, to see the actual timeframe where something happenend over 24h?

Right now i use Metric Search and played around with data transformations without success. Metric Queries cannot not be used, as it is limited to the last 3 hours.

[image: example]

[image: example2]

Comment: Does this help: [subquery-support](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/)